# Como direcionar submit de um form para o método de um plugin do Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, formulário, plugin, wordpress-theme

Estou estudando Wordpress, e para exercitar estou desenvolvendo um tema e um plugin. O objetivo é utilizar um formulário de contato no tema, que ao invés de enviar os dados por e-mail, como usualmente se faz, faça a persistência desses dados no banco para posterior visualização / manipulação pelo administrador do site.

A minha dúvida está em como utilizar o método de inserção de dados do meu plugin no `submit` do Formulário HTML. Vi na API do wordpress um arquivo chamado [admin-post.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-admin/admin-post.php/), mas ao que parece, não tem nada a ver com o que eu preciso fazer. Alguém tem uma idéia de como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Já existe um plugin que faz algo semelhante: Contact Form Database Extension. Talvez possa se guiar pelo que é a proposta deste.

Comment: Estude sobre hooks (actions e filters) do WordPress. Com esse conceito na sua cabeça vai ser mais fácil desenvolver no WordPress.